Is there a way to send a HEAD and GET request using php?
I would like to obtain the headers of a resource without actually downloading it, especially because I am trying to inspect headers of bigger media files. However the URLs are behind redirects, and I need to follow redirects to determine the actual headers of the media. I am not sure how many redirect are in place, and this can vary per URL.
In below answer it explains how to obtain the headers using POST and HEAD request:
curl -s -I -X POST http://www.google.com

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38679650
This works for my use case (using GET instead of POST), as I can obtain the headers such as the next redirect location without actually downloading the media. Then I can do this recursively following redirect, until I get the headers of the actual media.
However I have no idea how to perform BOTH a HEAD and GET request using php. Is this possible using some library such as guzzle?

This question is similar to: What is the easiest way to use the HEAD command of HTTP in PHP?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi @DarkBee, its not the same, I clearly asked how to use BOTH, HEAD and GET in the same command.

You can't execute two requests in one go. If you want the header details with a GET request then please have a look at CURLOPT_HEADER

@DarkBee Yes its possible, Its hackish but as in the link I referred to in my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38679650, its being done, and I tested and it works.

the whole point is getting a header response while using a GET request without actually downloading the content.

Why don't you just perform a HEAD request then if you don't need the body?

@DarkBee Because a HEAD does not return if there is a redirect or not, and does not return the redirect location. HEAD always returns 200.

curl -s -I -X POST means to send a POST request but only display head infomation. DarkBee is right, you feel it's hackish because you don't know that CURL hides the body.

@BernardWiesner - It doesn't demo

It could be the server of the media is badly configured when calling HEAD, cause its returning to me 200 even if its a 302 on GET.
curl -I -X GET https://serve.castfire.com/audio/4868779/4868779_2024-05-30-064519.128.mp3
VS
curl -I https://serve.castfire.com/audio/4868779/4868779_2024-05-30-064519.128.mp3

@BernardWiesner if the specific server is misconfigured and the HEAD request doesn't tell you anything useful, then I don't think you have much choice other than to make the GET request if you want to get the redirect headers. But in general, HEAD should be sufficient for this type of task, without needing to make two requests.

I had a similar problem years ago, where I just needed the http code of a request, but the HEAD request didn't return that same code as the GET request. I "solved" it by aborting the GET request as soon as I had the info needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717284/is-it-ok-to-terminate-a-http-request-in-the-callback-function-set-by-curlopt-hea

P.S. You said In below answer it explains how to obtain the headers using POST and HEAD request...but that's not what it's doing. It's just making a regular POST request, however cURL discards the body and just returns the headers. It's not making two requests in one. So I think your question is actually just based on a slight misunderstanding.

@ADyson yes maybe my wording was incorrect. However my goal was that the body doesn't get downloaded, and that works by using both GET and HEAD for my use case.

@ADyson As an example this does now download the 1GB file, but gives me the headers as if I had done a GET request.
"curl -I -X GET http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip"

that works by using both GET and HEAD...again, this doesn't use GET and HEAD simultaneously. A HTTP request can only have one method. It's true that -I would set the method to HEAD in curl, but in this case -X then overrides that again with GET. The side-effect of using -I as well as -X is that curl also gives you back the headers, which isn't done automatically otherwise. So as if I had done a GET request isn't right - it is a GET request.

Have you investigated RoToRa's suggestion from earlier? You said your server doesn't give you the right info from a pure HEAD request, so this could be a way to use a GET but stop downloading data once the headers are finished - a HTTP response always outputs the headers first.

@ADyson it is a GET request, I am not sure about that so. If its a GET request, why is it terminated early and does not actually download anything and only returns me the headers? Have you tried above curl? curl -I -X GET ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip

Thanks @RoToRa, yes I have tried this and it works as an alternative solution. However I have observed HEAD request are faster than using streaming and terminating it early, but its a alternative solution that also works.

why is it terminated early and does not actually download anything...before you said this does now download the 1GB file...so which is it? It downloads, or it does not download? You've given us two contradicting reports of the same thing

I apologize, that was a typo, I mean to say "this does not download the 1GB file"

Ah ok, thanks. Well, if you do, for example curl -v -I -X GET ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip (the -v means you get a verbose report of what curl is doing) you see that it certainly sends a GET request to the server. The curl manual isn't very clear about what exactly it does internally with this combination of options but it seems to me that it must be actually quite similar to the idea in RoToRa's link - it must just wait for the response headers, and then abandon the request before the main body download starts.

@RoToRa If you like you can answer with your solution since its basically what I want to do. ADyson and others, thanks for the help!

@BernardWiesner I think you should be able to do it with just the code the DarkBee published: $ch = curl_init($url);         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);         $response = curl_exec($ch);         curl_close($ch);         return $response; (https://www.darkbee.be/stack/curl/curl.php) but please double-check it

One possibility is to abort the GET request once you have received the header(s) you need. Example:
$url = "http://www.example.com/";

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => 'requestHeaderCallback',
));

$curlResult = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

function requestHeaderCallback($ch, $header) {
    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match("/^HTTP/\d.\d (\d{3}) /")) {
        if ($matches[1] < 300 || $matches[1] >= 400) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return strlen($header);
}

See also Is it ok to terminate a HTTP request in the callback function set by CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION?
